# Z-index внутри Grid-a

Tags: c#, wpf, z-index

Как поднять Z-Index, например, rectangle, который лежит внутри grid?

Вот как сделать это с canvas, я знаю:

```
canvas.childer.setzindex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Panel.SetZIndex(rectangle, 3);
```